# Старорусское имя

Tags: имена-собственные

Старорусские имена обычно понятные: Неждан, Сила, Владимир и т.д. А вот как быть, например, с именем Сысой? Или это имя не славянского происхождения?
Буду благодарен за подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА

1. Сысой - народная форма христианского имени Сисой (предположительно от древнееврейского слова, означающего шестой или беломраморный).
2. Имя Сысой происходит не из древнееврейского, а из древнеегипетского языка. На коптском языке (прямом наследнике древнеегипетского языка) имя Сысой звучало как Jijoi (преподобный Сисой Великий был коптом по национальности) и это имя упоминается ещё в Абидосском списке царей в качестве имени одного из фараонов (ок. 2700 г. до н.э.). В русский язык имя Сысой попало через христианскую греческую традицию. Именно на греческом языке имя Jijoi стало звучать как Sisoes. На коптском языке имя Jijoi означает "хохол", локон или клок волос, оставленный на голове. В Древнем Египте такая причёска была очень популярна.http://imya.com/name/32923
3. Сисой (в народе Сысой) в переводе с древнееврейского языка означает «шестой». Возможно, что такое имя получил родившийся на шестой день месяца или шестой по счету ребенок в семье. Надо сказать, что на Руси особой популярностью пользовались имена, которые были связаны с обстоятельствами рождения ребенка. Часто детей нумеровали по порядку рождения, называя латинскими, древнерусскими терминами. Поэтому столь распространенными стали фамилии - Одинцова, Третьякова, Шестакова, Шестунова, Семяхина, Осмехина и Сысоева.
   http://www.analizfamilii.ru/Sysoyeva/proishozhdenie.html?familiya=%D1%FB%F1%EE%E5%E2%E0

Answer (score 0):

Про Сысоя Вам уже сказали. Думаю, что никакого древнеегипетского следа там нет, поскольку христианских имена имеют  греческие, латински и древнееврейские корни.

Вам только стоит учесть, что термин "староруские имена" не слишком понятен. 
Были имена христианские и славянские (русские) некрестильные имена. Их иногда смешивают, но на суть это не влияет. При этом часть якобы славянских некрестильных имен (в т.ч. большинство женских) изобретено в XVIII веке представителями славянофильства (включая, например, Жуковского) и среди них есть совсем неславянские по происхождению.

Answer (score 0):

Преподобный Сисой Великий, благодаря которому имя Сисой попало в русские святцы, был по национальности коптом. Копты - прямые потомки древних египтян. Имя Сысой - коптское. Эту версию подтверждают многочисленные источники.

Очень подробно об этом написано здесь: http://sisoes.livejournal.com/